# Vectorization of the randi function in matlab with imin and imax range values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random, vector

`X = randi([imin,imax],___)` returns an array containing integers drawn from the discrete uniform distribution on the interval `[imin,imax]`.

I would like to create a vector of random integers, call it `Indx`, of size `50`. 
Assume I have a vector of integers, `Min`, and a vector of integers, `Max`, both of size `50`. Also assume that the first value of the vector `Min` is less than that of the vector `Max`, the second value as well, and so on...

What I would like to get is:

`Indx = randi([Min, Max],1,50)` which goes over the first elements of `Min` and `Max`, takes a random integer between them, places it in the first cell in `Indx`, then it goes over the second elements of `Min` and `Max`, takes a random integer between them, places it in the second cell in `Indx`, and so on..

And I would like to do this without the use of a for-loop. So basically using only 1-2 lines of code.

Is that possible?

Comment: `floor(rand(1,50).*(Max-Min+1))+Min`?

Comment: Great. Just what I needed. Thanks David! :)

Comment: @David you should post that as an answer